# What's wrong with RF/SVM with word embedding (GloVe)?

Tags: keras, word-embeddings, nlp, ensemble-modeling, gensim

I searched many times in google for examples on word embedding (specifically GloVe) with Random forest and I couldn't find any single example. For GloVe, it was all either LSTM or CNN. Maybe there's something I don't understand, but why only these 2 algorithms are used with GloVe, what's wrong with the other algorithms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually these are highly dimensional matrices, and all of the information can not be modeled by less-complex models like RF and SVM.